# Java (Jersey 2 + Grizzly 2) JAX-RS custom resource annotations for endpoints?

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

I'd like to annotate all of my JAX-RS Resources with some sort of "roles" attribute, that will be read through the context by an access control filter. An example of such a JAX-RS Resource is *(psuedo)*:

```
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource {

    @GET
    @Context(roles = "admin,user")
    public Response foo() {
      return Response.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Thus, the **AccessControlFilter** would have access to the resource-specific "roles" value:

```
public class AccessControlFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
    String accessToken = accessToken(context);
    String roles = context.getContext("roles");    

    // ... validate access Token against roles ...

  }

  @Nullable
  private static String accessToken(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    Map<String, Cookie> cookies = context.getCookies();
    Cookie accessTokenCookie = cookies.get("access_token");
    if (accessTokenCookie != null) {
      return accessTokenCookie.getValue();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I've been digging around:

- I see something of an implementation in the Jersey docs [Example 16.1. Using SecurityContext for a Resource Selection](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e12304), however I'm looking for a more vanilla API to build simple access control on.
- [Specifying Authorized Users by Declaring Security Roles](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjgcq/index.html)
- [Example 16.6. Applying javax.annotation.security to JAX-RS resource methods.](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12469)
- [How to access Jersey resource secured by @RolesAllowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817210/how-to-access-jersey-resource-secured-by-rolesallowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inject `ResourceInfo` into the filter class. From there you can get the resource `Method`. Then just use some reflection to get the annotation.

```
@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

@Override
public void filter(...) {
    Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
    MyAnnotation anno = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
    if (anno != null) {
        String roles = anno.value();
    }
}
```