# Security for RESTful web application username and password reside in database?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I want to provide security for my Web application.Already i provide it for 
Basic authentication .But now i want to provide UI to add user,privilege
option to user.I google it lot but not having idea.Please some one help me to do this.Any documentation ,articles also helpful for me.

BASIC Authentication descriptor :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>JerseyAuthentication</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.student.resource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/others/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
   <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>user</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>others</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/others/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>others</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my-default-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>others</role-name>
</security-role>
</web-app>
```

tomcat-users.xml :-

```
 <tomcat-users >
  <user username="Murugesan" password="secret" roles="admin" />
  <user username="peeskillet"  password="superSecret" roles="user"  />
 </tomcat-users>
```

Comment: In [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32667612/2587435) I explained that the tomcat-users (or UserDatabaseRealm) should not be used for production. It cannot be updated at runtime. I also linked to the documentation for how to create other types of realm, like the JDBC realm where it actually saves to a database. You should review that link.

Comment: ... and you should never store and unencryped / unsalted password.